# How to click an element within a table through Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I would like to click the cell in the table ID "ContractDesc", "EEE" content:

The HTML page:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="tablelist" id="table1" style="width: 80%; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 30%">
                AAA
            </th>
            <th>
                BBB
            </th>
            <th style="width: 40%">
                CCC
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead><tbody>


    <tr id="1" onmouseout="fnMouseOut(1)" =="" ""="" onmouseover="fnMouseOver(1)" onclick="selectRow(this)" style="cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);" projectid="111111">
        <td align="center" name="contno">
            DDD
        </td>
        <td name="ContractDesc">
            EEE
        </td>
        <td name="">
            FFF
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

My code that is not working:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="1"]/td[2]').click()
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_name("ContractDesc").click()
```

The error is:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="1"]/td[2]"}

Comment: Is the table in an `IFRAME`?

Comment: Yes, I think it's on the frame, Mr.JeffC.

Comment: @TZJ4, how is going? Did you check my answer? Thanks.

Comment: @RatmirAsanov No one can use, whole answers got error likes "unable to locate element". Thank you

Comment: @TZJ4, show us more HTML (iframe or popup or something else in which your needed web element).

Comment: Thank so much, switch to iframe now it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try this XPath:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@name='ContractDesc']").click()`

Please check if the element is in an iframe, if yes then you need to switch the driver to the iframe by using: `WebElement iFrame= driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));` and then `driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame);` and then you need to click the element by the given xpath and if you want to switch to the default context then you can use `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`

Comment: Thank you sir, but it still error "Unable to locate element:"

Comment: Please check if its in an iframe and if yes, you need to switch the driver to the iframe by using: `WebElement iFrame= driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));` and then `driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame); ` and then you need to click the element by `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@name='ContractDesc']").click()` and if you want to switch to the default context then you can use `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` Please try this and let me know if it works. I am editing my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath below to select by name and text, `normalize-space` remove all whitespaces:

```
//td[@name='ContractDesc' and normalize-space(.)='EEE']
```

Answer (score 1):

To `click()` on the element with text as **EEE** you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table.tablelist#table1 tr#1 td[name='ContractDesc']").click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='tablelist' and @id='table1']//tr[@id='1']//td[@name='ContractDesc' and normalize-space()='EEE']").click()
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much, but both are not work

CSS return error "A18-0110" and XPATH return "Unable to locate element:"